# Adobe AIR getQualifiedDefinitionNames

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a problem with getQualifiedDefinitionNames, when I compile with AIR 20 I get

> Main
>   gameBg_png$c19135a2672bad8837da970f47c7278f-30390368

and when I compile with Apach Flex 4.15.0 or Adobe Animate CC it returnes everything as expected!

> Main
>   Main__gamebg

how to fix it with AIR, that it returned Main__gamebg class?

my sample code:

```
package{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;  
   import flash.events.Event;  

   public class Main extends MovieClip {  

   [Embed(source="../assets/gameBg.png")]  

   public const _gamebg:Class;  

  public function Main() {  
    super();  
    if (stage) init();  
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);  
  }  

 private function init(e:Event = null):void {  

     removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);  
     var definitions:*;  
     if (this.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.hasOwnProperty("getQualifiedDefinitionNames")) {  
       definitions = this.loaderInfo.applicationDomain["getQualifiedDefinitionNames"]();  
       for (var i:int = 0; i < definitions.length; i++) {  
           trace(definitions[i])  
       }  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: why is this a problem?

Comment: Assuming you are compiling for Air MOBILE (not desktop) and most likely iOS as AOT'ing will generate those type of fully-qualified class names due the internal flatting of classes. If you are hard coding class names, you will have to parse the unique indentifer off the string and watch for possible name clashing at that point.

Comment: no I compile only swf using AIR 20 SDK and FlashDevelop, I tried using Animate CC (formerly Flash ) with AIR 20 SDK and it works as expected!

Comment: You did not answer the question, why is this a problem?

Comment: I am loading swf as a library and get classes with applicationDomain.getDefinition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/getqualifieddefinitionnames-porblem?replies=5#post-90611

this trick works.

```
///////////////
// SomeImage.as
///////////////
[Embed(source="someimage.png")] 
public class SomeImage extends Bitmap{
public function get dimensions(): String{
    return width + "x" + height;}
}

/////////////
// MyClass.as
/////////////
public class MyClas{
   public function foo(): void{
     // Instantiate the bound class to get the embedded image
     var someImage:SomeImage = new SomeImage();

     // ... do whatever you'd like with someImage
     trace("Dimensions: " + someImage.dimensions);
   }
}
```